# Data inputed incorrectly into R

Tags: r, rename

I currently have a dataset that has two variables, winner_entry and winner_seed. There are a few instances on where the data was incorrectly inputed. The winner_entry was incorrectly put into the winner_seed variable on a few instances.

```
Atp_singles_2022 %>%
  filter(winner_seed == "WC") %>%
  select(winner_seed, winner_entry, winner_name, tourney_name) %>%
  print(n=10)
```

This produces the output below
[image: What the code above produces]

Atp_singles_2022 %>%
mutate(winner_seed == str_replace_all(tourney_name, fixed("WC"),"NA"))

I was thinking to do this, but that wouldn't fix the winner_entry which needs to be changed to WC

Answer (score 0):

This may be solved using an ifelse statement within mutate.

```
Atp_singles_2022 <- Atp_singles_2022 %>%
mutate(winner_entry = ifelse(is.na(winner_entry),"WC",winner_entry))
```

This code says that if is.na(winner_entry) (AKA if winner_entry is NA), change it to WC, else leave it as winner_entry. With this code, you can change the contents of a column based on values in that column, or you could change it based on another column.

Comment: That didn't make the winner_seed turn into NA, it just made the winner_entry correctly display WC. Thus, now how to get winner_seed to say NA?

Comment: You can use a similar operation. mutate(winner_seed=ifelse(winner_seed=="WC",NA,winner_seed))

Comment: Works. Thanks for the help, for I was stuck on this problem for a while!